# Two different Prime Number Checker, Which is more effective

Tags: python

```
def prime_checker(number):
    if number % 2 == 0 or number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0:
        print("It's not a prime number")
    else:
        print("It's a prime number")
```

........

```
def prime_checker(number):
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            is_prime = False
        if is_prime:
            print("It's a prime number")
        else:
            print("It's not a prime number")
```

May I know which of both is more effective and should be used?

Answer and explain.......

Comment: That's easy: the most effective is the 2nd, since the 1st is incorrect (try it with 49...)!

Comment: The first one is faster but wrong. The second one is slower but right (though still not optimal -- trivially you see that the upper bound for `i` is no more than `sqrt(number)`)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is just straightup wrong, as it would identify 49 as a prime number. The second one is correct and therefore more efficient. To improve efficiency, one only has to check the numbers up to the square root of the number tho, since if A = a*b, then at least a or b must be smaller or equal than the square root of A. Also the second one will just print a statement after each iteration. So, a slight improvement in efficiency would be:

```
import numpy as np
def prime_checker(number):
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2,int(np.sqrt(number))+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            is_prime = False
    if is_prime:
        print("It's a prime number")
    else:
        print("It's not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct more effective, not the best performance tho.
The first one will fail in cases of a prime_number^2.

You can improve the second function to be effiecent.

```
def prime_checker(number):
    if number <= 1:
        print("It's not a prime number")
        return
    for i in range(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1):  # Only need to check up to the square root of the number
        if number % i == 0:
            print("It's not a prime number")
            return
    print("It's a prime number")
```

Checking up to the square root of the number is an optimization because if a number has a factor greater than its square root, then it definitely has a factor smaller than or equal to its square root.